# programmatic way to write a name on objects

Tags: java, image, jsp, image-processing, graphics

I have a need that I have to write text On images of object like

[image]

in my website from browser I have to select this pen which is in my database. . .

and change the quote("we keep you smiling "  to "save water save earth") and save the product again.

can any one help which way to move what technology to use. . for such kind of things. . I have a need for this kind of modification on predetermined set of products ( which are in our database) user have to select and change texts etc. . .

can any one help. . Thanks in advance.

Comment: This depends. If all the objects are the same (style), then you could create a template image which could be overlaid on top of the slogan.  The image you've presented is not a simple image and would take considerable processing to properly determine the best solution for each image, you'd probably end up doing it by hand and finding it faster...IMHO

Comment: yes the image is not simple. . . that is why i am mulling what shall be the way forward. . . as after changing the slogan i have so show to user how will it look like. .  do you have any idea what tool or technology we need to use. .  (images not change only text on them change). .

Answer (score 0):

if image set are always the same then you can paste a html tag over the image by managing the positioning manually for every image
then submit the form with image and the text provided

step 1 : ask user to select image
step 2 : according to the image selected pass position value from controller for selected image
step 3 : show the selected image and the text box at position passed from controller
step 4 : submit the form with image and text field